# Is Cassandra's thrift interface aware of compound keys table CQL3?

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql, cql3

Is there a way for Cassandra's Thrift interface to know in advance whether a particular client query will use a compound keys defined table (CQL3)? How can you know what the schema is for the table?

Comment: What do you mean by "in advance"? Do you mean something like an SQL prepared statement?

Comment: @Raedwald since compound key's tables return the data in a different format (see: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3). I'd like to tell when I'd need to parse the result set according the format.

Comment: So you are asking how can you know what the schema is for the table?

Comment: @Raedwald correct. I've figured that there's no way to do that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra stores the schema information in some system tables. You could query those to get the schema information that indicates that the rows have a compound primary key.

But you might want to reconsider why you want to do this. Your application program should know the schema of the tables it manipulates; it should already know what tables it uses and what their primary key is.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477616/how-to-execute-a-describe-cql-query-with-astyanax/) for details on how to determine the schema from system tables.

Anyways as Raedwald already said, you should probably ask twice why you'd want to do this.