# How to execute a "'describe" CQL query with Astyanax

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, astyanax, cql3

When you use `cqlsh` with Cassandra you can make a `describe` query to get the information of a table for example:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE emp;
```

And it will give you something like:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empid int PRIMARY KEY,
  deptid int,
  description text
) ...
....
```

So how can I query this using Astyanax support for CQL. I was able to query simple `SELECT` statements with this:

```
OperationResult<CqlResult<String, String>> result
            = keyspace.prepareQuery(empColumnFamily)
              .withCql("Select * from emp;")
              .execute();
```

But this isn't working for `DESCRIBE` statements.

PD: I am really doing this to get the `DATA TYPES` of the table, parsing it later and obtaining for example `int, int, text`, so please if you have a different approach to get those, it could be awesome.

This query `select column, validator from system.schema_columns;` doesn't work because it doesn't return the composite keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` is not part of the CQL spec (neither [CQL2](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html) nor [CQL3](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html)). If you'd like to completely reconstruct the `DESCRIBE` you could take a look at cqlsh implementation (look for `print_recreate_columnfamily`).

You could also get some more meta info from `system.schema_columnfamilies`:

`select keyspace_name, columnfamily_name, key_validator from schema_columnfamilies;`

Comment: Perfect, that was what I ended up doing.